# Tracking first time login from browser

Tags: cookies, azure-ad-b2c, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm trying to detect when someone logs in to my site from a new computer or new browser - like a bank would do.  And if that happens, trigger 2FA, send an email, etc.

So my plan was to add a cookie with a Guid in it and then look for that cookie with that Guid whenever they log in.  If the value wasn't there, then most of the time, it'd be a new device.

But I'm using Azure B2C and I believe it's overwriting my cookies (where I was storing my unique device id with an expiration of 1 year).  So after I login, I can see my cookie in the browser.  It's even there after I logout.  But after I login again using B2C, that cookie is gone.

I can see that I can have multiple cookie middleware, but I don't know how to access one scheme over another when I go to update the cookie in my code.

Does anyone know of any guidance or best practices on this?  Been driving me nuts.

TIA

{I've edited the question to be more clear.}

Comment: There's really not enough information here to answer you question. However, the use "bounce back", implies you're doing a redirection, which means different domains are likely at play. Cookies are domain-bound, so in order for two different things to see (read/write) the same cookie, they must be on the same domain. You cannot write something on one domain and then read it on a different domain.

Comment: Interesting. Makes sense, except that when I write my additional information to the cookie it shows up in the client browser and stays there even after I logout.  It's just when I go back through the actual login process again that it gets wiped out.  I'll look again for the domain information specifically.  Thanks for replying.

Comment: Chris, you were right about being unclear, so I edited the question.

Comment: Cookies have nothing to do with authentication. Cookie-based auth uses cookies, obviously, to persist the authentication, but cookies can be set with or without auth being involved.

Comment: Well then, it looks like I have some reading to do.  I just don't understand why I can't persist my own cookie. I'm doing something wrong.  I'm just seeing all the Asp.Net Core 2.1 docs referring to cookies as they pertain to auth.  Even that last comment is a help to this noob.  Thanks, Chris.